# How can I show XML graphically?

Tags: xml

I'm working on my thesis, the main goal of this thesis is to design and develop a graphical interface for XML languages.

Some features of this application will be:

- show XML graphically
- add/modify/delete a child
- add/modify/delete attribute
- browse two or more files in the same window and exchange data graphically, i.e. Move one child form file to file graphically
- create a link between two XML files then convert them to two SQL server tables

Can anyone help me how can I begin, how can I show xml graphically tree (GUI)?

Comment: What have you tried / researched? There are many approaches to do this. Why did you use tags like "jquery" and "vb" and "c#" and "sql"? Your question is kinda broad and can't be reasonably answered without further details on the problem.

Comment: I want to do it in asp.net . I don't know if I can use jquery or ajax , I'm just asking , plz help me

Comment: Help you with what problem? We are missing details. And you didn't even try to answer even one of them, please [show some effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) such that we can help you...

Comment: I want to do something like this link :

Comment: http://www.mxgraph.com/demo/mxgraph/orgchart.html
which is read from xml ,this link with money , I'm working individual so I can't buy this application .

Answer (score 0):

For showing the XML in a browser, you can use CSS - you can have a CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) file describing what font, size, color etc you'd like each element of the XML to have, and have the browser take it from there and display a more readable XML in the browser.

As far as reading all the children and their parents etc from the XML are concerned, you can try Python's `xml.dom.minidom` module. It parses the XML (provided it is valid) and provides easy access to the nodes of the XML tree.